# log4net is unable to load the file MySql.Data from GAC

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am trying to evaluate the use of log4net for my new Windows Services platform. I was hoping to use generate logs in my MySql database.

I have the latest of MySql (6.9.4.0) and log4net.

I have a create a simple windows console application and to that added a configuration file log4net.config which has my appender information.

Added the following line of code to AssemblyInfo class

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
and the following in my Program class
private static readonly ILog _debugLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

I have both log4net and MySql.Data Gaced in GAC_MSIL and both assemblies added to assemblyBinding section of the Application.config file

When I execute the program I see no logs generated. On turning on Apaches internal logging i see the error that it failed to load the MySql.Data file

Copy MySql.Data file to bin folder and the logs are generated absolutely fine.

Any clues?

Thanks
Regards
Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. The connection type element in the appender was missing the complete assembly name. It had MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data 
but should have had 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d

Works fine.